# JQUERY - Hide all table cells underneath table columns based on cell class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

we are currently developing an internal report for a client and I can't quite crack this one...

I have a HTML table with a variable amount of column headers and then a variable amount of data rows. Each  in the table is assigned a class of either 'td-Red' 'td-Green' or 'td-Grey'. This controls the colour of the cell.

If all of a column's tds have the 'td-Grey' class, we want to hide the entire column including the header.

I'm sure this can be done with jQuery but I'm failing to do so...

Is anybody able to help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through the headings , use heading index to filter data cells in each column that also have the grey class. Compare length of that collection to total rows and hide accordingly

```js
var $dataRows = $('#myTable tbody tr'),
   rowCount = $dataRows.length;
   

$('#myTable thead th').each(function(i){
   var $greyCells = $dataRows.find('td:eq(' + i + ').td-Grey');
   if($greyCells.length === rowCount){
      $greyCells.add(this).hide();      
      console.log('Hiding column index = ',i)
   } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Heading 1</th>
    <th>Heading 2</th>
    <th>Heading 3</th>
    <th>Heading 4</th>
    <th>Heading 5</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="td-Grey">Col 1</td>
    <td>Col 2</td>
    <td>Col 3</td>
    <td class="td-Grey">Col 4</td>
    <td>Col 5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="td-Grey">Col 1</td>
    <td>Col 2</td>
    <td>Col 3</td>
    <td class="td-Grey">Col 4</td>
    <td>Col 5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="td-Grey">Col 1</td>
    <td>Col 2</td>
    <td>Col 3</td>
    <td class="td-Grey">Col 4</td>
    <td>Col 5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="td-Grey">Col 1</td>
    <td>Col 2</td>
    <td>Col 3</td>
    <td class="td-Grey">Col 4</td>
    <td>Col 5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="td-Grey">Col 1</td>
    <td>Col 2</td>
    <td>Col 3</td>
    <td class="td-Grey">Col 4</td>
    <td>Col 5</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```